# Como manter o mesmo layout para as diferentes versões?

Tags: android, android-layout

Como posso manter o *layout* de meus aplicativos para as diferentes versões de Android?

Exemplo: Um `EditText` tem *layout* na versão 2.1 e outro nas versões 4.x, como manter o *layout* da versão 4 nas versões anteriores?

Comment: Caezar, você pode conferir nessa outra dúvida. [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71731/design-em-diferentes-vers%C3%B5es-do-android/71736#71736]

Answer (score 2):

Basta que você informe uma cor de fundo que ele já vai perder as características da versão. Exemplo:

```
<EditText
  android:background="#DDDDDD" />
```