# Design em diferentes versões do Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu só brinquei algumas vezes com Android e sempre tive problemas devido testar num smartphone com Android 4.0, por exemplo, tive que usar outro *RatingBar* por causa da incompatibilidade. 
Visto que o Material Design só está disponível para a versão 5.0, como ocorre a **"padronização"** do design de um app em diferentes versões de Android? É comum usar frameworks como o [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) para evitar isto?

Comment: Já olhou a biblioteca appcompat? Ela possui compatibilidade com versões antigas tais como ActionBar, dentre outras coisas que não estão disponiveis em versões 3.0-- @DanielaMarquesdeMorais

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniela, o `Ionic` é um framework JavaScript mobile HTML5 (como JQuery Mobile). Sim, a intenção destes frameworks é também padronizar o design, mas é um objetivo secundário. O objetivo principal destes frameworks é permitir ao desenvolvedor web a utilizar sua habilidade existente em HTML/JS para desenvolver apps mobile diminuindo o tempo e a curva de aprendizado. Obviamente, a consequência de mais desenvolvedores utilizando é que o design manterá um certo padrão (como houve com o Bootstrap).

No desenolvimento Android nativo, é possível utilizar bibliotecas de suporte para manter a compatibilidade entre as versões dos APIs, veja:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions

Comment: Um grande objetivo também é usar-se tecnologias web para **reduzir o custo** de se manter equipes de desenvolvimento para cada plataforma-alvo (iOS, Android, Windows Phone, etc.). Se a experiência 100% nativa não for um requisito essencial (performance top, UI customizada para cada plataforma), um aplicativo híbrido pode ser uma opção viável.

Comment: Exatamente, perfeita colocação!

Comment: Estou criando um projeto hibrido, sem duvida é uma vantagem quando não se conhece a plataforma android.

Answer (score 2):

Daniela,

você pode usar as bibliotecas de support para manter compatibilidade com várias versões do Android.

**Referência:** http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Já o Ionic é para criar aplicações mobile com HTML5.

É bom você acompanhar o blog de Developer do Android, veja esses links abaixo:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: Com isso então é possível aplicar o material design em versões inferiores a 5.0?

Comment: Sim, no caso de alguns componentes. Veja o segundo link (Android design support library).

Comment: Daniela, você também encontra bibliotecas no Android Arsenal [http://android-arsenal.com/]